# Entity Framework multiple navigation properties to the same table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with EF Code First and I can't find how to solve it:

Let's say I have this two POCO:

```
public class DocumentRequest
{
    // Database Id
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Origin
    public Guid OriginDocumentId { get; set; }
    public Document OriginDocument { get; set; }
    // Target
    public Guid TargetDocumentId { get; set; }
    public Document TargetDocument { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    // Database Id
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string DocumentMessage {get; set;}

    public Guid? FromDocumentRequestId { get; set; }
    public DocumentRequest FromRequest { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DocumentRequest> SentDocumentRequests {get; set;}
}
```

When I create a DocumentRequest from one Document, I create a copy of the document and then a document request:

The original document will have a DocumentRequest added to the SentRequests navigation property

The copied document will have the FromDocumentRequestId pointing to the DocumentRequestId

How would you configure code first to do that?

Comment: Can one document have multiple origins and/or targets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is the classes and configuration you need.

## Classes

```
public class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentMessage { get; set; }
    public DocumentRequest FromRequest { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DocumentRequest> SentDocumentRequests { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentRequest
{
    // One Document to one DocumentRequest
    [Key, ForeignKey("Document")]
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public Guid OriginDocumentId { get; set; }
    public Document OriginDocument { get; set; }
}
```

## DbContext

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentRequest> DocumentRequests { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // One Document to many SendDocumentRequests.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SentDocumentRequests)
            .WithRequired(x => x.OriginDocument)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OriginDocumentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

## Structure

[image: Structure]

## Sample Data

- Document (Id = 1) is inserted
- Document (Id = 1) is copied then Document (Id = 2) is inserted
- Document Request is inserted

  - DocumentId = 2
  - OriginDocumentId = 1
- Document (Id = 1) is copied again then Document (Id = 3) is inserted
- Document Request is inserted

  - DocumentId = 3
  - OriginDocumentId = 1

## Result

**Document**

```
Id
1
2
3
```

**Document Request**

```
DocumentId OriginDocumentId
    2            1
    3            1
```